# r class amelia object back to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Amelia is being used to impute missing values in a data.frame input. That process seems to be working. The input data set has column headers header_1, header_2, etc. The amelia command is:

```
imp1<-amelia(input, m=1, idvars = idvars)
```

The result from

```
str(imp1$imputations, 1)str(imp1$imputations, 1)
```

is:

```
$ imp1:'data.frame':    1725 obs. of  29 variables:
- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "mi" "list"
```

The command

```
xxx<-as.data.frame(imp1[[1]])
```

works to create data frame, however the variable names, column headers have been renamed to

```
imp1.header_1
imp1.header_2
etc
```

What is the correct way to run amelia to retain the original variable, header names? 
How can a data.frame with the original column headers be retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imp1$imputations` contains a list of data frames. Because you specified `m = 1`, there's only one data frame there. So you can access it with `imp1$imputations$imp1` and not worry about the `as.data.frame` call.

For example

```
data(africa)
a.out <- amelia(x = africa, 
                m = 1, 
                cs = "country", 
                ts = "year", 
                logs = "gdp_pc")

head(a.out$imputations$imp1)

  year      country gdp_pc  infl trade    civlib population
1 1972 Burkina Faso    377 -2.92 29.69 0.5000000    5848380
2 1973 Burkina Faso    376  7.60 31.31 0.5000000    5958700
3 1974 Burkina Faso    393  8.72 35.22 0.3333333    6075700
4 1975 Burkina Faso    416 18.76 40.11 0.3333333    6202000
5 1976 Burkina Faso    435 -8.40 37.76 0.5000000    6341030
6 1977 Burkina Faso    448 29.99 41.11 0.6666667    6486870
```

Comment: Can you point to a description of the (a.out$imputations$imp1) syntax. The command yyy <- (a.out$imputations$imp1) produces a correct result.

Comment: So you are getting what you want? Basically when you look at `str(a.out)` you can see it's a list with named elements. The `$imputations` part gets you into a list within the list (containing the imputed data sets), and then the `$imp1` part gets you the specific element from the list (one data frame). If you run it again with `m = 4` you'll see that `$imputations` will be a list of four datasets, one for each imputation. You could access each of those with `a.out$imputations$imp1`, `a.out$imputations$imp2`, `a.out$imputations$imp3`, etc.